# how to clear form on window before unload jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, forms, primefaces

In my application when a page with filled form values is closed and then opened using browser shortcut keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, the form contains the previously entered values I want to clear those form fields to their default values.

**Controller code for page load**

```
public void pageLoad()
{
    if(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()){ return; }
    purchaseOrderVO = new PurchaseOrderVO();
    purchaseOrderVO.setLastSevenDays(true);
    checkAll = false;
    loadVendorsList();
}public void resetForm()
{
    purchaseOrderVO = new PurchaseOrderVO();
    purchaseOrderVO.setLastSevenDays(true);
    purchaseOrderVO.setPurchaseOrderList(new ArrayList<PurchaseOrderVO>());
    logger.info("in reset form");
}
```

**xhtml trigering the pageLoad function**

```
<f:event listener="#{purchaseOrderController.pageLoad}" type="preRenderView" />
```

**xhtml trigering the resetForm function**

`<p:remoteCommand name="resetForm" action="#{purchaseOrderController.resetForm}" update="form1"></p:remoteCommand>`

**JQ for window before unload**

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
        resetForm();
        $('[id$=":form1]').trigger("reset");
    });
```

**pageLoad** is not called when page is opened using shortcut keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>,**resetForm** function is called but before the form can be updated the page closes i have also tried placing a timeout in JQ but its not resetting the form

Comment: This is the beauty of this shortcut!

Comment: Why so complex? Why not just use a viewscoped bean? Without caching

Comment: @Kukeltje tried both of your suggestion but none of them worked.